# Copying CSV file while reordering/adding empty columns

Tags: c#, list, csv

Copying CSV file while reordering/adding empty columns.

For example if ever line of incoming file has values for 3 out of 10 columns in order different from output like (except first which is header with column names):

```
col2,col6,col4 // first line - column names
2, 5, 8    // subsequent lines - values for 3 columns
```

and output expected to have

```
col0,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9
```

then output should be "" for col0,col1,col3,col5,col7,col8,col9,and values from col2,col4,col4 in the input  file. So for the shown second line (2,5,8) expected output is ",,2,,5,,8,,,,,"

Below code I've tried and it is slower than I want.

---

I have two lists.
The first list `filecolumnnames` is created by splitting a delimited string (line) and this list gets recreated for every line in the file.
The second list `list` has the order in which the first list needs to be rearranged and re concatenated.

This works

```
string fileName = "F:\\temp.csv";
//file data has first row col3,col2,col1,col0; 
//second row: 4,3,2,1
//so on

string fileName_recreated = "F:\\temp_1.csv";

int count = 0;
const Int32 BufferSize = 1028;
using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8, true, BufferSize))
{
    String line;
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    string orderedcolumns = "\"\"";
    string tableheader = "col0,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10";
    List<string> tablecolumnnames = new List<string>();
    List<string> filecolumnnames = new List<string>();
    while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        count = count + 1;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        tablecolumnnames = tableheader.Split(',').ToList();
        if (count == 1)
        {
            string fileheader = line;
            //fileheader=""col2,col1,col0"
            filecolumnnames = fileheader.Split(',').ToList();

            foreach (string col in tablecolumnnames)
            {
                int index = filecolumnnames.IndexOf(col);

                if (index == -1)
                {
                    sb.Append(",");
                   // orderedcolumns=orderedcolumns+"+\",\"";
                   list.Add(-1);
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(filecolumnnames[index] + ",");
                    //orderedcolumns = orderedcolumns+ "+filecolumnnames["+index+"]" + "+\",\"";

                       list.Add(index);
                }

                // MessageBox.Show(orderedcolumns);
            }
        }
        else
        {

            filecolumnnames = line.Split(',').ToList();

            foreach (int items in list)
            {

                //MessageBox.Show(items.ToString());

                if (items == -1)
                {
                    sb.Append(",");
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(filecolumnnames[items] + ",");

                }


            }
           //expected format sb.Append(filecolumnnames[3] + "," + filecolumnnames[2] + "," + filecolumnnames[2] + ",");
            //sb.Append(orderedcolumns);

            var result = String.Join (", ", list.Select(index => filecolumnnames[index]));
        }



            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName_recreated, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            }


    }
```

I am trying to make it faster by constructing a string `orderedcolumns` and remove the second for each loop which happens for every row and replace it with constructed string.
so if you uncomment the orderedcolumns string construction `orderedcolumns = orderedcolumns+ "+filecolumnnames["+index+"]" + "+\",\"";` and uncomment the append   `sb.Append(orderedcolumns);` I am expecting the value inside the constructed string but when I append the orderedcolumns it is appending the text i.e. 
`""+","+filecolumnnames[3]+","+filecolumnnames[2]+","+filecolumnnames[1]+","+filecolumnnames[0]+","+","+","+","+","+","+","`

i.e. I instead want it to take the value inside the filecolumnnames[3] list and not the  filecolumnnames[3] name itself.

Expected value: if that line has 1,2,3,4
I want the output to be 4,3,2,1 as filecolumnnames[3] will have 4, filecolumnnames[2] will have 3..

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" and other text not directly related to problem (like "new to C#, site,...") to questions. If you feel that thank you are important to your question - please discuss it first on http://meta.stackoverflow.com (but consider reading http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it first).

Comment: your code, when corrected, wont be faster. The corrected code end up looking like your original. If orderedcolumns is a string it will be much slower

Comment: modified my code to be exactly what I am trying to implement

Comment: sam, Please check if my edit reflects what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes alex thats the overall what i am trying to achieve

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov did you get a chance to look at my question? is it the down votes which is making my question to be not answered by anyone? so much of write up to get couple of negative votes :)

Comment: @sam I've updated my answer with what I would do.

Answer (score 1):

`String.Join` is the way to construct comma/space delimited strings from sequence.

```
var result = String.Join (", ", list.Select(index => filecolumnnames[index]);
```

Since you are reading only subset of columns and orders in input and output don't match I'd use dictionary to hold each row of input.

```
 var row = tablecolumnnames
       .Zip(line.Split(','), (Name,Value)=> new {Name,Value})
       .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x.Value);
```

For output I'd fill sequence from defaults or input row:

```
 var outputLine = String.Join(",",
      filecolumnnames
         .Select(name => row.ContainsKey(name) ? row[name] : ""));
```

Note code is typed in and not compiled.

Comment: I tried to do this but my list might have more column names than my actual columns, in that case I have to just set it to ",", modified my question

Comment: @sam you really should provide complete sample in the post - with constant values inline for everything involved.

Comment: I have added the complete code, the only part I am unable to add is the file which needs to be constructed as explained in the comment

Comment: @sam what about actual expected output? I suspect that simply adding set of empty columns could be enough (like `list.Select(index => filecolumnnames[index]).Concat(Enumerable.Range(0,6).Select(x=>""))` ), but since you only have sample for matching number for columns it is hard to see where problem come from.

Comment: The problem is i have to concatenate blanks all over the place, for example if my incoming file has col2,col4,col6 in the first line and as my tableheader = "col0,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10"; then output should be "" for col0,col1,col3,col5,col7,col8,col9,col10 and values from col2,col4,col4 in the file. so if the second line has 2,5,8 then my expected output is ",,2,,5,,8,,,,,"

Answer (score 0):

```
orderedcolumns = orderedcolumns+ "+filecolumnnames["+index+"]" + "+\",\""; "
```

should be

```
orderedcolumns = orderedcolumns+ filecolumnnames[index] + ",";
```

you should however use join as others have pointed out. Or

```
orderedcolumns.AppendFormat("{0},", filecolumnnames[index]);
```

you will have to deal with the extra ',' on the end

Comment: I cannot do this because I am trying to build my ordered columns only once and use it for all the other rows